# Help Me Evaluate A Conference

Tags: publications, conference, undergraduate, publishers, evaluation

I am now trying to get my article published before the end of the year. My advisor suggests me to submit my full paper to ICISE-IE 2022, a international conference on information technology and education. All past conference articles(full) are said to be published by IEEE and can be found on IEEE Xplore or EI Compendex. I want to know if it is worthy to give it a try.

The past conference information can be found in the following websites:

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/conhome/9418649/proceeding

http://www.icise2020.org/

http://www.allconfs.org/meeting/index_en.asp?id=9937

http://www.bjboku.com/index.php/cms/item-view-id-1379.shtml

https://10times.com/e1zp-g1x9-k3x5

Comment: Your advisor already suggested this conference. Did you ask them why? If not, why not? If yes, why don't you listen to their advice?

Comment: @Nobody They give me such advice according to my subject. One of my co-author think this conference is a spam, which is what I am worrying about.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you can filter out suspicious conferences at a glance by looking at the chair, keynote speakers and past history. The latter is also the most important: if you skim through titles/abstracts of the conference archives, that gives you a pretty decent idea relatively fast.
A quick look at the provided info tells me that is a fairly domestic conference at best, possibly preying on people confusing it with the regular ICISE, which is a much larger event. They also play a good ol' trick of "just invite a few colleagues from the neighboring countries and call it international".

So, going through this checklist:

- It is by no means large, so if you intend to present your results big time, do not bother
- The chair and keynote speakers are almost exclusively Chinese - it is possible not fitting in (e.g. by not speaking Mandarin) would be a hindrance for networking
- The 2020 event at least is incredibly short: there is just one day of presentations and another of "Academic investigation activities", whatever that means
- I am not nearly an expert in your field, but the website of the company behind it looks bit shady. In particular, seeing phrases such as "Some of the members have an H-index between 10 and 30 and all of them have good reputations in this field" (1) or "After strict review, accepted papers are published by Conference Publishing Services and submitted to IEEE Xplore, EI Compendex, Scopus, Inspec, DOAJ, and CPCI (Web of Science) after publication." (2) is very alarming.

1: In other words: "This conference is very legitimate, promise!". No one could possibly know prominent authors in their respective fields without conferences telling them about how good they are!
2: "Strict review" immediately raises ALL the red flags. Being peppered with metric-related words like that is also not what I would expect a reputable conference to do, but maybe it is field-specific or a cultural/translation issue. Or maybe they are just trying really hard to take off as a new venue - why not?

Going with a gut feeling, that would be a pass - or, rather, discussing it with the advisor in more detail. Usually there is a pretty good and concise answer to "why yes?"

Comment: Thank you!!!! This information is very valuable. Wish everything the best of you!